# Remove everything after a pattern (.com)

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Driving myself nuts.  I am trying to get just the domain name (http://www.example.com) out of  access.log. What the log looks like:

```
tail access.log 

Fri, 13 Jul 2012 20:32:03 -0700,INFO,6fgmd8fk,params,http://www.example.com/images/CIV-260.jpg|
```

I have tried many variations of this one-liner ([with sed and awk](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/141885-awk-removing-data-before-after-pattern.html)):

```
tail -4 access.log |grep http |awk {'print $6'} |cut -c28- |awk '$1>".com"' |sort |uniq

http://www.example.com/2713-7807.jpg|
http://www.example.com/2713-7808.jpg|
http://barfoo.com/img/14616_20120711182527.jpg|
http://foobar.com/css/14616_20120713142151.css|
```

I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -Po '(?<=http://)[^/]+' access.log | sort -u
```

If you want to have `http://` as a part of domain name,

```
grep -Po 'http://[^/]+' access.log | sort -u
```

Comment: @jdorfman: Just an FYI, you can use `tac` to reverse the stream instead of `sort -nr`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just

```
awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

if you don't have more '/' than you example shows.
Notice this is just the domain name, as your question asks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's|.*\(http://[^/]*\)/.*|\1|p' access.log | sort -u
```